# IE11 Metro/Modern showing menu bar

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

Since the latest couple of upgrades IE11 Metro/Modern version permanently shows the menu bar at the bottom. Usually, clicking inside the page showing would make it disappear downwards, now it remains taking up valuable screen real estate.
Is this supposed to happen? If so, can I turn it off somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% that this is your issue - but try going to "Options" and turning off "Always show address bar and Tabs".